# Beanstalk apps connecting using https

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have spring app A running in beanstalk.
A is internally calling app B using http. It’s working fine.
Now I added a listener in load balancer in app B and enabled https.
Now A is not able to call B using https and having certificate exception.
Please let me know if I need to make any change in app A for disabling certificate validation or if there is any other way.
App A is calling app B using web client. Both apps are running in beanstalk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have your **own domain** (e.g. `myapp.org`). You can't use HTTPS with a default EB domain provided to you by AWS. Once you have your own domain you can get an SSL certificate using AWS ACM. The full procedure for setting up HTTPS on EB is described in [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-https-configuration/).